# foreach with doParallel doesn't work with more than 1 core

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, logistic-regression, doparallel

I'm facing a problem when I launch this function :

```
  blocs <- split(df, 1 + (1:nrow(df)) %% ncores)
  cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  if (mode == "batch"){
    res <- foreach(i = blocs, .combine = "cbind", .export = c("batch_gradient_descent", "sampled_df", "add_constant", "sigmoid", "log_loss_function")) %dopar% {
      coefs <- batch_gradient_descent(df, colnames(X), colnames(y), learning_rate, max_iter)
    }
    return(res)
  }
```

When I run it with 1 core, it works. When I go with 2 or more cores, it doesn't enter in my foreach function, nothing happen and I have no error.
I might miss something but after a lot of searching hours, impossible to find a solution !

Can someone give me a hint on this case ?

Comment: Your problem description is not detailed enough. How do you know it doesn't enter the loop? How do you know nothing happens? You should provide a minimal, self-contained and reproducible example that allows us to investigate this.

Comment: Sorry Roland, it's only my second post on stackoverflow. I'll do my best next time and will be more precise. Danlooo helped me and it works well!
About your question : it didn't enter the loop because i try to make a simple "print("ok") and nothing appeared on the console.

Comment: The parallel workers cannot print to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blocs <- split(df, 1 + (1:nrow(df)) %% ncores)` will produce `ncores` many batches containing identical data (e.g. just 3 copies). Try to do sth. like this instead:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(doParallel)
ncores <- 3
df <- iris

blocs <-
  df %>%
  mutate(batch = row_number() %% ncores) %>%
  nest(-batch) %>%
  pull(data)
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

res <- foreach(i = blocs, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
    Sys.sleep(5)
    coefs <- mean(i$Sepal.Length)
}
```

Comment: Thank you danlooo, my blocs are created and I see them when I print blocs, but now I'm facing a new error and it seems to come from my dataset. Do you know something about this error ?

Error in data.frame(value, row.names = rn, check.names = FALSE) : 
  'row.names' should specify one of the variables

Comment: There is sth wrong the the value of `rn`. Please open a new question for a new issue.